# Is there a short-hand for setting a different color / style / width to each side of the CSS border?

Tags: html, css

I want to set a different color / style / width to each side of the CSS border.

Is there a short-hand for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can get is doing this:

```
selector
{
    border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #f00 #0f0 #00f #f0f
}
```

Although if you've got a mostly uniform border with one side different, for example, I'd go with daveoncode's answer.

Comment: you win for having one line lesser

Comment: Why thank you Pacerier! One line in the grand scheme of things doesn't really matter, but it's definitely nicer having to type less.

Answer (score 6):

You have to declare each single border:

```
.my-box {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 3px dashed black;
  border-right: 2px dotted violet;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

If you want you can override just the borders with the different style:

```
.my-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 2px dotted violet;
}
```

Comment: +1 for overriding the style. Probably the simplest, easiest trick even if it might not be the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

No, the shortcut is just for one border. There is no way you can fit width, style and color in one shortcut for all borders if those borders differ. Would be nice to have something like

```
border: 1px solid Red, 2px solid Green, 2px solid darkgeen, 1px solid Pink;
```

but it's not the case. For the example above you will have to do something like:

```
border: 1px solid Red;
border-right: 2px solid Green;
border-bottom: 2px solid darkgreen;
border-left-color: Pink;
```

Comment: There is a uniform shorthand `border` property and there's a shorthand for each side, so there are in fact (at least) five shorthand properties.